# What is the difference between Value and ObjectValue in JavaFX properties?

Tags: java, javafx

I am looking at this diagram:

[image]

and still can't understand the difference between Value and ObjectValue. For example, what must return `WritableValue<String>#getValue()` method and `WritableObjectValue<String>#get()` method ?

Comment: They do the exact same thing. If you look at the source code, `getValue` calls `get`. And everywhere in the javafx library only `get` contains the actual logic. (if you read the javadoc, you'll find a simular answer)

Comment: @n247s If they are same, why did javafx developers separate them? Why do we have ObservableValue and ObservableObjectValue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The developers of JavaFX wanted to have primitive-compatible observable values. Otherwise, every number used in JavaFX would have to be the wrapper types (e.g. `Integer`) which would have affected performance. However, `ObservableValue` can only deal with references. To solve this, they created sub-interfaces for the common primitive types as well as some common reference types (e.g. `String`). These interfaces take the form of `ObservableXXXValue`.

These `ObservableXXXValue` interfaces define a method, named `get`, that returns the specific type the interface is for. For instance, the `ObservableIntegerValue`'s `get` method returns `int`. If you look at the hierarchy, you'll see:

- `Observable`

  - `ObservableValue<T>`

    - `ObservableObjectValue<T>`

      - `ObservableStringValue`
      - `ObservableListValue<E>`
      - `ObservableSetValue<E>`
      - `ObservableMapValue<K,V>`
    - `ObservableNumberValue`

      - `ObservableIntegerValue`
      - `ObservableLongValue`
      - `ObservableFloatValue`
      - `ObservableDoubleValue`
    - `ObservableBooleanValue`

The `WritableValue` interface follows the same pattern with `setValue` and `set`<sup>1</sup>.

The `ObservableNumerValue` interface extends `ObservableValue<Number>` and provides some `Number`-like methods (e.g. `intValue`). Then each of its subinterfaces provide `get` methods for the primitive types they represent (e.g. `int`). The `ObservableBooleanValue` does the same for `boolean`.

The `Observable[List|Set|Map]Value` interfaces are somewhat special. For example, `ObservabeListValue` extends *both* `ObservableObjectValue<ObservableList<E>>` and `ObservableList<E>`. This allows implementations to behave like an observable value and an observable list at the same time. These interfaces weren't added until a little later (JavaFX 2.1).

The `ObservableObjectValue` and `ObservableStringValue` interfaces exist, I assume<sup>2</sup>, to provide symmetry—both in principle and to mirror the `WritableValue` interfaces.

So, to answer your question directly, there is no difference between `get` and `getValue` when it comes to `ObservableObjectValue`. There *is* a difference between `get` and `getValue` when it comes to interfaces like `ObservableIntegerValue` where `get` returns an `int` and `getValue` returns a `Number`. Thus, implementations deal directly with primitive types for both access and storage.

---

<sup>1. `WritableValue` also provides `getValue` and its sub-interfaces provide the appropriate `get` methods. However, it is not observable (doesn't extend `Observable` or `ObservableValue`).</sup>
<sup>2. Assumption confirmed by @fabian in the comments.</sup>

---

This gets even more interesting when dealing with the implementations. I won't go into too much detail, but will give one example hierarchy.

- `ObservableStringValue`<sup>^</sup>

  - `StringExpression`

    - `StringBinding` *implements `Binding<String>`*
    - `ReadOnlyStringProperty` *implements `ReadOnlyProperty<String>`*

      - `ReadOnlyStringPropertyBase`
      - `StringProperty` *implements `Property<String>` and `WritableStringValue`*

        - `StringPropertyBase`

          - `SimpleStringProperty`<sup>*</sup>

            - `ReadOnlyStringWrapper`<sup>*</sup>

<sup>^ An interface.</sup>
<sup>* A concrete class.</sup>
<sup>No markings means abstract class.</sup>

And to note:

- `ReadOnlyProperty` extends `ObservableValue`
- `Binding` extends `ObservableValue`
- `Property` extends `ReadOnlyProperty` and `WritableValue`

Comment: Your assumption is indeed supported by the javadoc of `WritableObjectValue.get()`: [*"This method exists only to align WritableObjectValue API with WritableBooleanValue and subclasses of WritableNumberValue"*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/beans/value/WritableObjectValue.html#get--)

Comment: `ObservableStringValue extends ObservableObjectValue<String>` but not `ObservableStringValue extends Observable<String>`, so why do we have in `ObservableStringValue` `get` and `getValue`?

Comment: @Pavel_K I edited my answer. Please let me know if it's still satisfactory.

Comment: good answer - you might consider to remove those code tags from class names to make it readable ;)